# How to publish npm package with auth token? Error 401 - Unauthorised. You must be logged

Tags: node.js, npm, token

Something weird is going on when I try to publish my package on npm without login by auth token.

I've set the `export NPM_TOKEN="..."` variable inside my `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bash_aliases` files.

Also, I've set an `npm config set '//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken' "${NPM_TOKEN}"` command from my CLI.

Despite on this, every time I wanna publish my package I receive an error:

`npm ERR! 401 Unauthorized - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/ics - You must be logged in to publish packages.`

Perhaps someone knows how to publish packages via npm auth tokens? Well, if I made a login via username & password all is going well. Btw I don't need to be logged in case I want to publish some package via auth token right? It's how most of CI/CD works nowadays.

NPM Token is valid. Generated in "Read & Publish" mode and set locally just several minutes ago.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did your problem solve? If yes, how? I'm facing similar issues.